# Is there a way to limit the print to only true congruences?

Tags: python, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on this code to calculate Fermat's Little Theorem and it works as it should. The only issue that I have is that I would hope for it to be more efficient. Is there a way to limit the print to only true congruences?

```
for i in range (1,351):
    print i, [(2 << i - 2) % i == 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't even works for me, it gives an error: `ValueError: negative shift count`. 
But considering it's working for you somehow, you can use an `if` condition to print only when true:

```
for i in range (2,351):  # changing 1 to 2 fixed the error for me.
    if (2 << i-2) % i == 1:  # this will check if it's true, then only print
        print i, [(2 << i - 2) % i == 1]
```